Creating a custom diagonal line QBrush tiled pattern in PyQt5?
So, at first I wanted to use a gradient background to emphasize certain cells / items in my QTableView, but as it can be seen in Stretchable QLinearGradient as BackgroundRole for resizeable QTableView cells in PyQt5?, I could not quite get that to work.
Then I thought maybe I could somehow use CSS to define the gradient background and Qt properties to control which items it is shown on, however the problem is that in a QTableView, the cells / items are QStyledItemDelegate, and as noted in https://forum.qt.io/topic/84304/qtreewidget-how-to-implement-custom-properties-for-stylesheet :

Dynamic properties can only be applied to QWidgets!

Is it possible to apply the property on the selected item only?

no, not directly. Unless you subclass a custom QStyledItemDelegate and initialize the StyleOption for the painted index according to your widget's property.

So then looking at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbrush.html I saw there are different patterns that can be chosen for QBrush, and in fact I liked Qt.BDiagPattern diagonal line pattern / hatch - but the lines were too thin for my taste.
So, I wanted to customize the line thickness for the BDiagPattern, and I found Can I customize own brushstyle? which has an example of how to draw a QPixmap and use it as a texture pattern that repeats / tiles, however, it does not demonstrate how to do diagonal lines.
So, I came up with this example:
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QPointF, QEvent)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QColor, QGradient, QLinearGradient, QBrush, QTransform)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
# starting point from https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/qtableview-modelviews-numpy-pandas/

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data
        self.parent = parent
        self.bg_col1 = QColor("#A3A3FF")
        self.bg_col2 = QColor("#FFFFA3")
    #
    def create_texture(self): # https://stackoverflow.com/q/62799632
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(QtCore.QSize(16, 16))
        pixmap.fill(QColor(0,0,0,0)) # without .fill, bg is black; can use transparent though
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(pixmap)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("blue")))
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(self.bg_col1, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawLine(pixmap.rect().bottomLeft(), pixmap.rect().topRight())
        painter.end()
        return pixmap
    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            # See below for the nested-list data structure.
            # .row() indexes into the outer list,
            # .column() indexes into the sub-list
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if index.column() == 2:
                print( f"{self.parent.table.itemDelegate(index)=}" )
                brush = QBrush(self.create_texture())
                brush.setTransform(QTransform(QTransform.fromScale(4, 4))) # zoom / scale - https://stackoverflow.com/q/41538932; scales pixels themselves
                return brush
    #
    def rowCount(self, index):
        # The length of the outer list.
        return len(self._data)
    #
    def columnCount(self, index):
        # The following takes the first sub-list, and returns
        # the length (only works if all rows are an equal length)
        return len(self._data[0])

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        data = [
          [4, 9, 2, 2],
          [1, 0, 0, 0],
          [3, 5, 0, 0],
          [3, 3, 2, 2],
          [7, 8, 9, 9],
        ]
        self.model = TableModel(data, self)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()

... however, as you can see from the output screenshot:

... the diagonal lines don't quite "flow" into each other - in other words, the pattern does not tile.
So, how can a draw a diagonal line pattern that tiles nicely, with custom line thickness, using QBrush and QPixmap?

Just wanted to document this, as it took some hours of digging to get something that I thought works. Well, there are two things here:

For one, the diagonal line from bottom left to top right needs to be offset, so it "centers" nicely along the diagonal
But for the pattern to tile / repeat nicely as a whole, we also must draw similar diagonal "lines" (or line portions) at the top left and bottom right corners of the pixmap as well

Here is the corrected code:
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QPointF, QEvent)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QColor, QGradient, QLinearGradient, QBrush, QTransform)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
# starting point from https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/qtableview-modelviews-numpy-pandas/

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data
        self.parent = parent
        self.bg_col1 = QColor("#A3A3FF")
        self.bg_col2 = QColor("#FFFFA3")
    #
    def create_texture(self): # https://stackoverflow.com/q/62799632
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(QtCore.QSize(16, 16))
        pixmap.fill(QColor(0,0,0,0)) # without .fill, bg is black; can use transparent though
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(pixmap)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("blue")))
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(self.bg_col1, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawLine(pixmap.rect().bottomLeft()+QPointF(1,0), pixmap.rect().topRight()+QPointF(1,0))
        painter.drawLine(pixmap.rect().bottomRight()+QPointF(-1+2,1), pixmap.rect().bottomRight()+QPointF(1+2,-1))
        painter.drawLine(pixmap.rect().topLeft()+QPointF(-1+0,1), pixmap.rect().topLeft()+QPointF(1+0,-1))
        painter.end()
        return pixmap
    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            # See below for the nested-list data structure.
            # .row() indexes into the outer list,
            # .column() indexes into the sub-list
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if index.column() == 2:
                brush = QBrush(self.create_texture())
                brush.setTransform(QTransform(QTransform.fromScale(4, 4))) # zoom / scale - https://stackoverflow.com/q/41538932; scales pixels themselves
                return brush
    #
    def rowCount(self, index):
        # The length of the outer list.
        return len(self._data)
    #
    def columnCount(self, index):
        # The following takes the first sub-list, and returns
        # the length (only works if all rows are an equal length)
        return len(self._data[0])

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        data = [
          [4, 9, 2, 2],
          [1, 0, 0, 0],
          [3, 5, 0, 0],
          [3, 3, 2, 2],
          [7, 8, 9, 9],
        ]
        self.model = TableModel(data, self)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()

I kinda brute-force looked up the offsets in the code above, but I find the end result decent:


Some notes: 1. creating the pixmap (and transforming it) for every data() call is very inefficient, since it's always the same; create it in the __init__ instead (including the scaling); 2. Just use QPainter(pixmap), and you can also avoid the call to end() since the painter is being immediately destroyed (it would only be necessary if you plan to use the pixmap within the same scope in which the painter has been created); 3. the new pixmap isn't always black: it's "random" data from allocated memory; 4. pixmap.fill(Qt.transparent) is slightly faster (and more readable);


Similarly, QtGui.QColor(Qt.blue), as using constants/enums is faster than parsing the color string (both with SVG names or the #rrggbb syntax), which is one of the reasons for which QColorConstants was created; 6. QTransform(QTransform.fromScale(4, 4)) is redundant; 7. functions that have default keyword arguments should always respect the same signature in their overrides: the index (which should actually be named parent) in rowCount() and columnCount() should be keyworded, possibly defaulting to None (for mono or bi-dimensional models) or QModelIndex() (for tree models).

